# WebRTC SDK iOS RTCIceCandidatePairStats

Tags: ios, webrtc

I'm trying to log RTCIceCandidatePairStats with the WebRTC iOS SDK. I am able to access the RTCLegacyStatsReport. Does anyone know how to get this information on iOS:
https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-stats/#dom-rtcicecandidatepairstats

Answer (score 0):

Yep, those are the ones. Not sure why they are called RTCLegacy, perhaps because RTC no longer uses them?

Either way, those are the correct stats. They will give you all the info you need (bitrate/framesize/cpu%/etc)

Just for sanity sake use

```
- (void)statsForTrack:(nullable RTCMediaStreamTrack *)mediaStreamTrack
     statsOutputLevel:(RTCStatsOutputLevel)statsOutputLevel
    completionHandler:(nullable void (^)(NSArray<RTCLegacyStatsReport *> *stats))completionHandler;
```

And then traverse the reports in the array for the stat you want. We use

```
googFrameHeightInput
googFrameHeightSent
googFrameRateInput
googFrameRateSent
googHasEnteredLowResolution
packetsLost
packetsSent
googEncodeUsagePercent
```

To give us an accurate QOS

Comment: That is the function we are using. I've been asked to track availableOutgoingBitrate. Maybe it has a different name on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

```
yea John was right and we use the same for WebRTC stats you can use standard or debug stats level based on your requirement. 

\\ here connection is your - RTCPeerConnection
\\ track is your current video track
\\

\\ a small example of how we are using it 

func updateStats() {
    for stream in streams.values {
        guard stream.videoTracks.first!.isEnabled else { continue }
        let track = stream.videoTracks.first!
        connection.stats(for: track, statsOutputLevel: RTCStatsOutputLevel.standard) { [weak self] reports in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            guard reports.count == 3 else { return }
            guard reports[2].reportId.hasSuffix("_recv") else { return }

            let data = reports[2].values
            guard let trackId = data["googTrackId"] else { return }

            self.streamStats[trackId]?.previousStats = nil
            let stats = StreamStats(data: data, previousStats: self.streamStats[trackId])
            self.delegate?.client(client: self, statsUpdated: stats, forTrackId: trackId)
            self.streamStats[trackId] = stats
        }
    }
}
```